# How to keep the position of an element fixed after removing it

Tags: python

I've created a basic memory game that creates a matrix of cards, and upon receiving user input will 'flip' and reveal the card. When two cards are matched, it will remove the pair from the matrix. However, upon playing the game I've run into two problems with card placement– upon removing the cards, cards after the removed card takes the removed cards place, and jumbles up the order of the cards, removing the 'memory' aspect of the game. It looks something like this:

The cards automatically resume position oriented to the left, and weirdly enough sometimes one or two cards pop up on top of the whole card layout, which is the second problem.

```
def remove_pairs():
    matrix[row][col].pop()

    for i in range(len(matrix)):
        for j in range(len(matrix[0])):
            try:
                print((matrix[i][j][1]), end = ' ')
            except IndexError:
                print("  ")
        print('')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    create_deck()

    p1_score = 0
    p2_score = 0

    card1 = None
    card2 = None

    while True:
        card1 = get_card()
        print(card1)
        card2 = get_card()
        print(card2)
        if card1[0] == card2[0]:
            remove_pairs()
        else:
            continue
```

I've tinkered a bit but can't figure out how to remove the cards in their original position, as well as fix the problem of the card appearing on top of the layout. How would I go about fixing this?

Comment: Remove the overhead that doesn't contribute to exhibiting the problem: set-up, user input, etc.  Include the debugging traces you've done.  See this lovely [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog for help.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to replace the card with a "empty" placeholder instead of removing it.  Then it would be easy to keep the structure of the matrix, but you'll have to add some checks to see if the user picked an "empty" spot.  And you might want a new icon or something to display in the "empty" spots.

Comment: Hi, so in the remove_pairs function, i changed 

matrix[row][col].pop()

to 

matrix[row][col] = ''

and still got something similar to the above code.

Comment: What do you mean by something similar?  Are you still having a problem with the first card being printed on it's own line?  Or are you still having problems with the cards being shifted over to the left?